# Trying to write a generic function for parsing JSON into codable Structs

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I'm currently parsing JSON like this

```
struct ExampleStruct : Codable {
     init() {

     }
     // implementation
}

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let object =  try decoder.decode(ExampleStruct.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch {
        print("Coding error - \(error)")
    }
}
```

This works fine, however I've been trying to learn about Generics over the weekend.  I'm trying to write a method which I pass in a Codable struct type and a string of JSON which returns the object of type I want back.

I've tried the following :-

```
func getType<T>(_ anyType: T.Type, from jsonString:String) -> T? {

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let object =  try decoder.decode(anyType, from: jsonData)//Errors here
        return object as? T
        return nil
    } catch {
        print("Coding error - \(error)")
       return nil
    }
  }
return nil
}
```

and then when I want to do the above

```
 if let exampleStruct:ExampleStruct = getType(type(of: ExampleStruct()), from: jsonString) {
  print(exampleStruct)
 }
```

However on the let = object line  I get the following errors

> Cannot convert value of type 'T' (generic parameter of global function 'getType(*:from:)') to expected argument type 'T' (generic parameter of instance method 'decode(*:from:)')

and

> In argument type 'T.Type', 'T' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'

As I said I've just been trying to learn about generics this weekend but I've clearly hit a block in my understanding.   Is there a fix for this, indeed is what I'm trying to do even possible or a good idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it's highly recommended to hand over an error of a `throw`ing function to the caller.
Second of all `Data` created from an UTF8 string can never fail.

You have to constrain the generic type to `Decodable`, it's not needed to pass the type as extra parameter.

Your function can be reduced to

```
func getType<T : Decodable>(from jsonString:String) throws -> T {
    let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
}
```