# Generic parser method for decodable and serializable

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, decodable

I am trying to write a generic parser method which will parse data with respect to return type.

**Edit**

We get complex json response from multiple servers. Sometimes same response model could mean different things or vice versa. My target is to inject parsers to my repositories/services. And get the same result at the end.

**Edit End**

**Edit 2**

For "FeedTypeSerializable" custom init method should be called

For "FeedTypeDecodable" should be called.

**Edit 2 End**

```
protocol FeedResponseProtocol {
    var feed : String { get }
    var success : Bool { get }
}


protocol Serializable {
    init(_ json : [String:Any])
}
```

Structure which could be constructed using JSON object

```
struct FeedTypeSerializable : FeedResponseProtocol, Serializable {
    
    var feed: String
    var success: Bool
    
    init(_ json: [String : Any]) {
        feed = ""
        self.success = false
    }
    
}
```

Decodable Struct

```
struct FeedTypeDecodable : FeedResponseProtocol {
    var feed: String
    var success: Bool
}

extension FeedTypeDecodable : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case feed, success
    }
}
```

Finally my parser protocol and implementation. I am getting two different error for trying two different things

1: Error : Cannot convert value of type 'Decodable?' to expected argument type 'T.Type'
I want to know how I could cast one protocol to another, if possible

2: Error : Static member 'init' cannot be used on instance of type 'Serializable'

```
protocol ParserProtcol {
    func getFeed<T : FeedResponseProtocol>(forData data: Data) -> T
}

struct FeedParser : ParserProtcol {
    func getFeed<T>(forData data: Data) -> T where T : FeedResponseProtocol {

        if T.self is Decodable {
            let response : T = JSONDecoder().decode((T.Type as? Decodable), from: data)
// 1: Error    
        }
        else if T.self is Serializable {
            do {
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                let response = (T as! Serializable).init(jsonObject)
//2: Error shown
                }
                catch {
                    //error handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Serializable` protocol is seriously flawed. Not all JSONs are a `Dictionary`. Also, why do you need it in the first place? What value does it add that `Decodable` does not have already? Using `[String:Any]` is also a big red flag. You should avoid using `Any` as much as possible.

Comment: This is a common mistake: The type argument of `decode(_:from:)` **must** be a concrete type. You can use a generic constrained to `Decodable` but never `Decodable` itself.

Comment: ... and this kind of runtime type check is pretty ugly and *unswifty*. Write two methods with the same signature once constrained to `Decodable` the other to `Serializable`. The compiler will choose the proper one (at compile time).

Comment: @DávidPásztor, your point is valid. Actually I provided this code just to give a general idea.  And why I need it, we have pretty complex json structure coming from multiple servers. My target to achieve is, I could inject parsers to repositories/services. These parsers will parse response and return a struct conforming to a protocol. I'll add this info to question also.

Comment: @vadian, you comment is making sense to me. Can you guide me to some code example/documentation/tutorial

Comment: @ibnetariq [Trying to write a generic function for parsing JSON into Codable structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909240/trying-to-write-a-generic-function-for-parsing-json-into-codable-structs) explains how to correct your decodable.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, I am already using this. My problem is, in most cases I would be using JSONDecoder. But in select few cases, I would like to call init with Dictionary, where I can check key/value pairs and take decisions accordingly. And example would be I get "Users" and "UsersList" from two different servers. So "FeedTypeDecodable" uses JSONDecoder and "FeedTypeSerializable" uses custom init method

Comment: @ibnetariq you can easily handle that using `JSONDecoder` and `Codable`, no need to manually parse a `Dictionary`. On how to do that, check [swift 4 Codable - how to decode if there is string or dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077932/swift-4-codable-how-to-decode-if-there-is-string-or-dictionary/54078158#54078158)

Comment: This question and accepted answer explains one of the issues I'll face -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236188/use-multiple-codingkeys-for-a-single-property

I want to take two different approaches based on need.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, vadian suggestion was different than the link you provided. A solution is possible. Can you please revert the [duplicate] tag, so I can post answer and get it reviewed from community.